# Use grepl() to match two elements of a string with separators with two column values in a dataframe simultaneously

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

I have a dataframe as shown below and the desired output is shown below.

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("abc_1_102", "abc_1_103", "xyz_1_104")
)


selection <- data.frame(col1 =c("abc", "xyz"),col2 =c("102", "106"))
```

**Desired output**

```
       col1      col9
1 abc_1_102 SELECT
2 abc_1_103 NOTSELECT
3 xyz_1_104 NOTSELECT
```

How can we achieve this using grepl() function in R

What I have tried?

```
df$col2 <- ifelse(grepl(paste("^", selection$col1, "$", collapse = "|"), df$col1)&
                          grepl(paste("^", selection$col2, "$", collapse = "|"), df$col1),
                        "SELECT", "NOTSELECT")


print(df)

       col1      col2
1 abc_1_102 NOTSELECT
2 abc_1_103 NOTSELECT
3 xyz_1_104 NOTSELECT
```

Here, the result is incorrect as in the selection the values in column1 and column2 match the first and third element of value in row 1 of df.

Comment: What have you tried? are you concerned about sub-pattern matches? is it always in the same order? This and your last question seem under-described and under-constrained. Have you tried anything? I'd think simple use of `paste` or `paste0` and `grepl` would be just as useful here as in your last question.

Comment: Further ... are your `selection` rows supposed to match one-for-one with your `df` rows, or is the fact that they both have 3 rows coincidental?

Comment: @r2evans I have now edited the post to reflect your comments. I did try using the last code. Didn’t work.

Comment: While I think we can resolve this question, I wonder if this is an X/Y problem, where you are solving individual steps of a larger problem that may be resolved in a completely different way. For instance, if you have a frame of data (like `df`) and another frame that you want to make selections or matches to (either "at least one match exists") specific selections of ("find the exact row that matches") and do something with the two.

Comment: @r2evans yeah, this does have that kind of smell. vp_050, are you trying to filter the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more complete example would be preferable, but from what I understand, you want to see if there are any of the rows of `selection` (with a separator of `_1_`) in `df`, with the column being "SELECT" when TRUE and "NOTSELECT" otherwise.

```
df$col9 <- ifelse(grepl(paste(selection$col1, selection$col2, sep = ".*", collapse = "|"), df$col1), "SELECT", "NOTSELECT")
```

Notes:

1. If the separator is important to you, then you can replace `.*` with `_1_`
2. Instead of "SELECT" and "NOTSELECT", use TRUE and FALSE. It's shorter, simpler, harder to mess up, and all round a better way of doing things

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `_` is a safe separator of the multiple fields in `df$col1`, we can do this:

```r
ifelse(
  grepl(paste(sprintf("(^|_)%s_.*_%s(_|$)", selection$col1, selection$col2),
              collapse = "|"), df$col1),
        "SELECT", "NOTSELECT")
# [1] "SELECT"    "NOTSELECT" "NOTSELECT"
```

The `(^|_)` matches either a preceding `_` (assuming there is something to the left of that underscore) or the beginning of string. Similarly, `(_|$)` for end-of-string. I'd normally use boundaries (e.g., `\\b`), but underscore does not match that, so no boundaries are found.

Comment: Remind again your preference for `sprintf(` in many `regex` use cases.

Comment: `sprintf` has nothing on to do with regex, it's mostly a choice between `sprintf` and `paste`, and I find sometimes it is clearer to combine multiple string elements with the former than the latter. Both work find, both produce a string that can be used as a regex pattern.

Comment: yes, shouldn't have mixed in regex, but the %s, %d etc in order is often much easier than nested `paste`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`interaction`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/interaction) with `sep = ".*"` to build the patterns in `grepl`, e.g.,

```
transform(
    df,
    col9 = paste0(
        ifelse(grepl(
            paste0(interaction(selection, sep = ".*"), collapse = "|"),
            col1
        ), "", "NOT"),
        "SELECT"
    )
)
```

which gives

```
       col1      col9
1 abc_1_102    SELECT
2 abc_1_103 NOTSELECT
3 xyz_1_104 NOTSELECT
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `separate()` `df$col1` into two columns and then use these to
`left_join()` the `selection` dataframe.

```r
library(tidyverse)

selection$select <- "SELECT"

res <-
  df |>
  separate(
    col1,
    into = c("char", "num"),
    sep = "_1_",
    remove = FALSE
  ) |>
  left_join(selection, join_by(char == col1, num == col2)) |>
  replace_na(list(select = "NOTSELECT"))

res
#>        col1 char num    select
#> 1 abc_1_102  abc 102    SELECT
#> 2 abc_1_103  abc 103 NOTSELECT
#> 3 xyz_1_104  xyz 104 NOTSELECT

# To make the result exactly as specified:
res |>
  select(col1, col9 = select)
#>        col1      col9
#> 1 abc_1_102    SELECT
#> 2 abc_1_103 NOTSELECT
#> 3 xyz_1_104 NOTSELECT
```